# Understanding Perl´ error in printed midway output

Tags: perl

I have had a lot of problems with a Perl script.
This script calculates the distance between my data set.

(If you want to reproduce the example with the real data, please visit here:https://github.com/MauriAndresMU1313/Example_Tajima-Nei_Distance_Bioperl)

The script works, but the output is incomplete.
This is the script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::AlignIO;
use Bio::Align::DNAStatistics;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $idfile = $ARGV[1];

if ($file eq "" ) {
  $file = "NT_MSA_S.fasta";
} elsif ($idfile eq "" ) {
  $idfile = "NT_ID_S.csv";
}


#### Considerando un archivo
my @contentIDS;

open (LIST, $idfile) or die;
while (my $l = <LIST>) {
  $l =~ s/\n//g; # eliminar newline
    $l =~ s/\r//g; # eliminar retorno de carro
  next if (length($l) < 1);
  push @contentIDS, $l;
}
close LIST;

#### .... colocar la lista de ids del fasta de forma ordenada y no redundante en el array
my $stats = Bio::Align::DNAStatistics->new();
my $alignin = Bio::AlignIO->new(-format => 'fasta', -file   => $file);  ### $file es el alineamiento # probar con alphabet
while (my $aln = $alignin->next_aln) {
  #print "reading...A\n"; ### DIAG
  my $matrix = $stats->distance(-align => $aln, -method => 'TajimaNei');
  #print "reading...B\n"; ### DIAG
  ### Obtaining values for each pair (DISTANCE!)
  WL1:
  foreach my $aaa (@contentIDS) { ### identificador #1
    WL2:
    foreach my $baa (@contentIDS) { ### identificador #2
        next (WL2) if ($aaa eq $baa);
      my $data =  $matrix->get_entry($aaa, $baa);
      #($data = 0) if ($data < 0);
        print "DISTANCE\t$aaa\t$baa\t$data\n";
    } # END WL2
  } # END WL1
}

exit;


#
```

My output has 98282 rows, my problem is that the row 1 to 314 the distance is empty, but then the distance was calculated:

```
                                         Calculation
(1) DISTANCE    AVP78031.1  AVP78042.1  
(2) DISTANCE    AVP78031.1  ATO98108.1  
(3) DISTANCE    AVP78031.1  ATO98120.1  
...
(315) DISTANCE  AVP78042.1  ATO98108.1    0.29731
(316) DISTANCE  AVP78042.1  ATO98120.1    0.29281
...
(98282) DISTANCE QNB17852.1 QNB17840.1   0.00026
```

When I see the output message error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $data in concatenation (.) or string at Tajima-Nei_Distance_NV.pl line 43, <GEN0> line 22294.
Use of uninitialized value $data in concatenation (.) or string at Tajima-Nei_Distance_NV.pl line 43, <GEN0> line 22294.
Use of uninitialized value $data in concatenation (.) or string at Tajima-Nei_Distance_NV.pl line 43, <GEN0> line 22294.
...
```

This error line is the same: 626 times.
I don´t understand why line 43 in the Perl script is wrong. Besides, when I see line 22294 in the output file:

```
(22294) DISTANCE    ALR69641.1  ALT66880.1  0.00222
```

The distance was calculated in this line of the output. I really don't understand that.

Does anyone have an idea why this is this? Is a problem with the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes `$matrix->get_entry($aaa, $baa)` returned undef. Anytime you try to get perl to interpolate a string with a variable that is undefined and warnings enabled, then you get that warning.

The line

```
    print "DISTANCE\t$aaa\t$baa\t$data\n";
```

gets interpolated and `$data` is undef and so you get the warning you mentioned.

```
$ cat x.pl
use warnings;
my $x = undef;
print "$x\n";
$ perl x.pl
Use of uninitialized value $x in concatenation (.) or string at x.pl line 3.
$
```

You're printing the value of `$aaa` and `$baa` each time and only 3 times does it print an empty string for `$data`. Those are the inputs which are not "gotten". The matrix is undefined for those 3 tuples. You need to investigate those 3 specific tuples, which only you can do because you haven't shared that specific input.

---

UPDATE 1

Using perl 5.20.2, Bio::AlignIO version 1.7.8, and the data you included in your github project, I cannot reproduce your problem:

```
$ time perl "Bioperl Script" "Fasta file" "ID list" > perl.out 2>&1
```

Instead I see, in the redirected output, these warnings emitted by `$stats->distance` as it executes:

```
MSG: ti_index not defined for R  (359 times)
MSG: ti_index not defined for Y  (209 times)
MSG: ti_index not defined for N  (69123 times)
```

Then I see your code's output (I uncommented your TWO diag print statements):

```
---------------------------------------------------
reading...A                      (this is printed only once)
reading...B                      (this is printed only once)
DISTANCE    AVP78031.1  AVP78042.1  0.03064
DISTANCE    AVP78031.1  ATO98108.1  0.30081
DISTANCE    AVP78031.1  ATO98120.1  0.29663
... thousands of lines elided
DISTANCE    QNB17852.1  QNB17759.1  -1.00000
DISTANCE    QNB17852.1  QNB17771.1  0.00052
DISTANCE    QNB17852.1  QNB17783.1  -1.00000
DISTANCE    QNB17852.1  QNB17840.1  0.00026
```

The first 3 (a,b) tuples in my output match yours except the `$data` value for mine *is* defined whereas yours is undefined.

This perl script executes for over 12 minutes on my 2019 MacBook Pro. The fact that the "reading" lines appear only once in the output indicate the `while` loop iterates only once.

My guess is that you are using an older version of this module that handles its warnings in a different manner.

Comment: Thank for answer, I understand, however, why that variable was fine in the other lines of the script but not when the line corresponds to 22294. What I'm trying to say is that line 43 worked for the vast majority of the script but not for a few lines. Any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/MauriAndresMU1313/Example_Tajima-Nei_Distance_Bioperl here is my Github example with one of my real data set. Please let me know if you can reproduce the analysis and if the problem appears again! @JeffHolt

Comment: I got it, I going to try to update the module version, on the other hand, when you reproduce the analysis, do you the same script or change something? I ask this only for curiosity. Anyway, thank you for your help!